# Error while accessing current uid of firebase user in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, uid

I want to get the current uid of user with flutter.

I have tried following but returns an error

```
final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    void inputData() {
      final User user = auth.currentUser;
      final uid = user.uid;
      print(uid);
      // here you write the codes to input the data into firestore
    }
```

Error:

```
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════
[core/no-app] No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase.initializeApp()
```

Comment: Do a web search for that error message.  Did you call `initializeApp()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase has now been updated and requires you to initialize Firebase before using any firebase products.
Also make sure your pubspec.yaml file has firebase_core:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_core : ^0.5.0
```

And mainly initialize Firebase in your main function of main.dart

```
Firebase.initializeApp();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call `Firebase.initializeApp()`

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
   WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
   await Firebase.initializeApp();
   runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Turns out firebase_core was missing

Comment: That is the simple need to import package in pubspec.ymal file if we want to use third party pacakge.